# How to compress an Image to a certain size?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I want is, when someone upload an image bigger than 1MB it get compressed and resized to be 1MB.
I am using http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/ if this can help me doing this task

Comment: Does this need to be exact, or would "about 1MB" be ok?

Comment: A quickscan of the tool: When you request a picture you can specify the size. This is not what you want. You want the picture resized when it is uploaded.

Comment: There's too many different ways to compress an image to a given size.  You can throw away quality.  You can simply shrink it.  You can crop it. You can change the file type of the picture...

Comment: @EricPetroelje about 1MB

Comment: I don't want to crop it, resize will be the best, but how I know which size will give me less than 1MB file size

Comment: There isn't a *good* way to force a size, although it's possible.  See the question I linked to for some ideas.